# Metadata's key must match seed of ['metadata', program id, mint] provided

Tags: solana-program, metaplex-js

So the issue is revolving around this part of my code:

```
    const myKeypair = loadWalletKey("/root/.config/solana/id.json");
    const mint = new web3.PublicKey("pubAddr");
    const seed1 = Buffer.from(anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("metadata"));
    const seed2 = Buffer.from(mpl.PROGRAM_ID.toBytes());
    const seed3 = Buffer.from(mint.toBytes());
    const [metadataPDA, _bump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([seed1, seed2, seed3], mpl.PROGRAM_ID);
    const accounts = {
        metadata: metadataPDA,
        mint,
        mintAuthority: myKeypair.publicKey,
        payer: myKeypair.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: myKeypair.publicKey,
```

I am not sure what this is getting at, I am trying to update my tokens metadata but I've been running into numerous issues.

connection side of code:

```
    let ix;
    if (INITIALIZE) {
        const args : mpl.CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs =  {
            createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
                data: dataV2,
                isMutable: true,
                collectionDetails: null
            }
        };
        ix = mpl.createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(accounts, args);
    } else {
        const args =  {
            updateMetadataAccountArgsV2: {
                data: dataV2,
                isMutable: true,
                updateAuthority: myKeypair.publicKey,
                primarySaleHappened: true
            }
        };
        ix = mpl.createUpdateMetadataAccountV2Instruction(accounts, args)
    }
    const tx = new web3.Transaction();
    tx.add(ix);
    const connection = new web3.Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");
    const txid = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [myKeypair]);
    console.log(txid);
```

When I try running this, I get the following error: `Metadata's key must match seed of ['metadata', program id, mint] provided`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't provide information about the error, just the user's code.

Comment: I disagree, I believe the title of the question is the error the user is getting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the Upgrade Authority is the same as the Mint Authority and the key you're using?

What error are you receiving (I see the title, but I'm not certain)?